# JavaScript element colouring only works after text via document.writeln

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js function that takes an html node and fades it from yellow to white. But it only works if before calling it from my js file I add text to body element via document document.writeln('Hi');. If I write text directly in my html file and don't call document.writeln then I don't see the fade effect after opening index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="program.js"></script>
</head>
<body style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
      Hi
</body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```
'use strict';

document.writeln('Hi'); // If we comment out this line we don't see the fade effect.

// Define a function that sets a DOM node's color
// to yellow and then fades it to white.

var fade = function (node) {
    var color = 1;
    var step = function () {
        var hex = color.toString(16);
        node.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF' + hex + hex;
        if(color < 15) {
            color++;
            setTimeout(step, 100);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(step, 100);
};
fade(document.body);
```

EDIT:

Using window.onload for fade function also does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use this one and it works without any errors:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
fade(document.body);});
```

If the DOM is not loaded yet, you can't change it. So, this listener might help.

As described here, if you call Document.writeln() the browser calls Document.open() before, so there is an existing Document object. That might be the reason, why it worked, when you added this line before.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score 1):

You can also move the `<script src="program.js"></script>` to right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Tried it and nothing changed - tried it this way: 
 `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script src="program.js"></script>
<body style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
   Hi
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Try it like this:
`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>Hi<script src="program.js"></script></body></html>`

Comment: This works, but how can I reach the same result without moving the script tag to the body element? And can you explain why this works?

Comment: html file:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="program.js"></script>
</head>
<body style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
Hi
</body>
</html>`
js file:
`$(document).ready(function() {
    fade(document.body);
});`
paste your 'fade' function here

Comment: I actually can't use any libraries so jQuery is not an option for me. Can I reach the same result with window.onload  or document.onload?

Comment: `window.onload = function () {
    fade(document.body);
};`

Answer (score 0):

Is the function wrapped in a

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Function goes here
});
```

or a

```
window.onload = //function name here
```

if not, use either one & it should be working

**EDIT** 
I've forgotten to say that you shouldn't forget to add jQuery before the external js file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried using the function in window.onload `window.onload = fade(document.body);` but it does not help. And i'm not using jQuery so i can't use '$'